Repository method doesn't work in ApplicationListener in Spring Boot
I have service for handling login attempts
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LoginAttemptEmailServiceImpl implements LoginAttemptEmailService {

    public final static int EMAIL_LOGIN_ATTEMPT = 5;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void registerFailureLogin(String email) {
        UserEntity user = userRepository.findByEmail(email).get();
        LoginData loginData = user.getLoginData();

        if(loginData.getLoginAttempts() >= EMAIL_LOGIN_ATTEMPT){
            loginData.setLoginDisabled(true);
        } else {
            loginData.setLoginAttempts(loginData.getLoginAttempts() + 1);
            loginData.setLastLoginAttemptTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        }
        UserEntity savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
        System.out.println(savedUser.getLoginData());
    }

}

and ApplicationListener where method registerFailureLogin is called
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationFailureListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {

    private final LoginAttemptEmailService loginAttemptEmailService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {
        String email = event.getAuthentication().getName();
        loginAttemptEmailService.registerFailureLogin(email);
    }
}


problem: line UserEntity savedUser = userRepository.save(user); doesn't save user i db
but if i call method of this service - 'registerFailureLogin' in ordinary CommandLineRunner it works.
@SpringBootApplication
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EcommerceMarketplaceApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    private LoginAttemptEmailService loginAttemptEmailService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommerceMarketplaceApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        loginAttemptEmailService.registerFailureLogin("vitaliyverzyn25@gmail.com");
    }
}


Hard to say without the log... wild guess: there's an Exception thrown somewhere and there is already a Transaction - marked 'rollBack only' -  when registerFailureLogin is called
